# Update d3 Graph in node.js javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reload

i have a function `drawGraph` as prototype looking as the following:

```
Presentation.prototype.drawGraph = function() {
var _this;
this.margin = {
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0
};
this.width = 1000 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
this.height = 1000 - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
this.singleWidth = 50;
this.singleHeight = 32;
_this = this;
return d3.json("data.json", (function(_this) {
   return function(err, json) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    d3.select("#backbutton").on("click", function(e) {
        _this.removeRenderedContent();
        return _this.clickOnBackgroundRect();
    });
    d3.select("#updatebutton").on("click", function(e) {
        try{
            $.get('http://localhost:3000/data');
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
        //code for updateGraph
    });
    _this.x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, _this.width], 0, 0);
    _this.y = d3.scale.linear().range([_this.height, 0]);
    _this.svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg").attr("width", _this.width + _this.margin.left + _this.margin.right).attr("height", _this.height + _this.margin.top + _this.margin.bottom).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 50 + ")");
    _this.svg.append("rect").attr("x", -200).attr("y", -200).attr("width", 1200).attr("height", 1200).attr("fill", "#FFFFFF").on("click", function(data, index) {
        _this.removeRenderedContent();
        return _this.clickOnBackgroundRect();
    });
    _this.groups = _this.svg.selectAll("g").data(json).enter().append("g").attr("class", function(data, index) {return "group-case " + data.type;});
    _this.groups.on("click", function(data, index) {
        _this.removeRenderedContent();
        _this.clickOnGroupCaseRect(data, index, this);
        return false;
    });
    _this.groups.attr("transform", function(data, index) {
        return "translate(" + data.x + "," + data.y + ")";
    });
    _this.groups.append("rect").attr("width", _this.widthFilter).attr("height", _this.heightFilter).attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0).attr("rx", 10).attr("ry", 10);
    _this.groups.append("g").append("text").attr("y", 7).attr("x", 7).text(function(data) {return data.title;}).call(function(data, xpadding) {return _this.wrapGroup(data, xpadding);}, 7);

    _this = _this;
    return _this.groups.append("g").each(function(data, index) {
        return _this.drawChildren(this, data, index);
    });
};
})(this));
};
```

I want the graph to be updated on click event of `#updatebutton`. I looked into many examples, but can't get it work for my code. Does anyone know how to reload my Graph?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: In your `click` event handler for `#updatebutton`, you don't  have a success callback:  `$.get('http://localhost:3000/data', function(data) { // code to update graph });`

Comment: I know that, thanks anyways. But my Question was more related to the code for updating the graph. What do i have to execute in the success callback?

Comment: Your question really doesn't have enough detail to answer that.  Is this a line graph, bar, something else?  What is `_this.drawChildren`; is that the initial draw of the graph?  Without having enough code to reproduce your troubles, it's very difficult to help.

Comment: `drawChildren` is another function in the same file which is called. Yes this is the initial call of the graph! Do you need the code of that function? @Mark

Comment: Yes.  It's impossible to say how to update a graph without any details of how the graph is created.  When asking questions, you should strive to provide enough detail that we can re-create the situation.  If I can't take the above code, fire up jsFiddle or Plunker and run it, you haven't given enough detail...

Comment: alrigt, thanks for your help. here's a jsfiddle with the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/wqgzck27/2/ I hope u can access it.